# Amplitude Encoding via Ventura-Martinez leads to Division-by-0?

Tags: encoding

I'm confused about the middle step of Ventura-Martinez' algorithm for amplitude encoding ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9807054.pdf)). According to Schuld-Petruccione (also Jacquier/Kondratyev) we construct and apply to the ancilla $a_2$ a $2 \times 2$ operator that contains the expressions $\sqrt{\frac{\mu-1}{\mu}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}}$
with $\mu = M + 1 - (m + 1)$ where $M$ is the number of amplitudes I want to encode and $m$ is the current step, which should range from $1$ to $M$.

The problem: Well, for $M = m$, this results in a division by zero, as $\mu = 0$ at the last step. What am I missing?